# (In)formal equivalent for "Sword of Damocles" concept

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, idioms, idiom-requests

What are the formal and informal equivalents (idiom or word) for the situation which [**Sword of Damocles**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damocles#Sword_of_Damocles) could describe that?

From [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sword-of-damocles), Sword of Damocles means:

> If you have a sword of Damocles hanging over you/your head, something bad seems very likely to happen to you.
>
> **E.g.** The threat of a cut in funding is hanging over the Opera House like a sword of Damocles.

Answer (score 3):

[Sword of Damocles](http://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/sword-of-damocles):

> - One regarded as an imminent danger:
>
>   - ***menace, threat.*** Idiom: ***[clear and present danger](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/clear-and-present-danger).***

(yourdictionary.com)

Answer (score 2):

[***have a [dark/storm] cloud hanging over one's head***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=615&bih=403&tbm=bks&q=%22cloud+hanging+over+your+head%22&oq=%22cloud+hanging+over+your+head%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...8032.14309.0.14976.19.14.1.0.0.0.329.2257.0j2j4j3.9.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..11.2.375...30i10.9orlikU0KDw)

> (storm clouds) Used in reference to a threatening or ominous state of affairs: *the beginning of the decade saw storm clouds gathering over Europe.*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/storm-cloud?q=storm+cloud)
>
> *It was still a dark cloud hanging over my head. A Sword of Damocles. Every time I saw that a partner was calling me on the phone, I held my breath.*
>
> [Ever After: Broken Book 3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IF-MAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=%22cloud+hanging+over%22+%22sword+of+damocles%22&source=bl&ots=xAJ0H9R6Gc&sig=Ay7At6djtlx9YF6koBun7SwLjH0&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiuYvHns_MAhWrA8AKHX-tBtUQ6AEIIjAE#v=onepage&q=%22cloud%20hanging%20over%22%20%22sword%20of%20damocles%22&f=false)
>
> *Throughout the Cold War, we lived with the threat of nuclear holocaust hanging over our heads like a dark cloud.*
>
> [Defense Special Weapons Agency](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Gx6Tk7GluyIC&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22the+threat+of%22+%22like+a+dark+cloud%22&source=bl&ots=RtbGik-C22&sig=cEwWN71x7pnRaVrzVi_oO4b4pto&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRxJffo8_MAhVmLMAKHSXbBisQ6AEIIjAE#v=onepage&q=%22the%20threat%20of%22%20%22like%20a%20dark%20cloud%22&f=false)

***be staring one in the face***

> 1. To be imminent or unavoidable to (one): *Bankruptcy now stares us in the face.*
> 2. To be about to experience or undergo (**something dire**): *We are staring bankruptcy in the face.*
>
> [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stare+in+the+face)
>
> *The threat of a cut in funding is staring the Opera House in the face.*

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to appear in any online idiom lists or dictionaries, but one option is:

[A knife to the jugular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knife%20to%20the%20jugular&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknife%20to%20the%20jugular%3B%2Cc0)

(link is to Google NGram viewer)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jeopardy](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=jeopardy) - Risk of loss or injury; peril or danger.

Also, [kafkaesque](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Kafkaesque) - Marked by surreal distortion and **often a sense of impending danger**.